# Microsft Office start too slow when having network without internet

Tags: networking, performance, microsoft-office

When I connect my Network Cable (with no internet) Microsft Office run too slow (about 30 sec).

But if I disconnect the cabel or access the internet to network Microsoft Office will run immediately. I'm Using Windows 10 and Office 2021.

I confused with this Problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: I suggest you start Office applications in [safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-office-apps-in-safe-mode-on-a-windows-pc-dedf944a-5f4b-4afb-a453-528af4f7ac72) when having network without internet. Safe Mode can help us check if it is caused by a third-party add-in. If you are using a network printer, it is also recommended to set the virtual printer as the default to check the problem.

Comment: thank you for answareing
i checked befor But in safe Mode still have paroblem 
both Office and windows are recently install and its New
no network printer insall in this Cumputer But i have some Network Printer in my Network